# ORACLE and TRIGGERS (inserted, updated, deleted)

Tags: oracle, triggers

I would like to use a trigger on a table which will be fired every time a row is inserted, updated, or deleted.

I wrote something like this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER test001
  AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON tabletest001
  REFERENCING OLD AS old_buffer NEW AS new_buffer 
  FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new_buffer.field1 = 'HBP00')
```

and it works. 
Since I would like to do the same things if the row is inserted, updated, or deleted, I would like to know what's happening in the trigger.
I think I can manage to find if the row is inserted or updated (I can check the old_buffer with the new_buffer).
How can I know if the row has been deleted?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From [Using Triggers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_tr.htm):

> Detecting the DML Operation That Fired
>   a Trigger
>
> If more than one type of DML operation
>   can fire a trigger (for example, ON
>   INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE OF
>   Emp_tab), the trigger body can use the
>   conditional predicates INSERTING,
>   DELETING, and UPDATING to check which
>   type of statement fire the trigger.

So

```
IF DELETING THEN ... END IF;
```

should work for your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. I have some problems with DELETING.
I guess it is not trapped cause of this condition new_buffer.field1 = 'HBP00'.

Comment: How can you pass these information to other (e.g.) functions? For example, say I want to compute a value depending on whether it is inserting/updating/deleting and I have to do this in dozens of triggers. I'd like to make the code as DRY as possible, so ideally I'd like to be able to do `value := my_func(INSERTING, UPDATING, DELETING, ...other params)` and just copy&paste that line in all my triggers... but what type should I give to the 3 parameters of `my_func`? Would this even work? Or we must use `if inserting then my_insert_func(...other params) elsif updating then my_update_func(...)` ?

Answer (score 34):

I've changed my code like this and it works:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER test001
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON tabletest001
  REFERENCING OLD AS old_buffer NEW AS new_buffer 
  FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new_buffer.field1 = 'HBP00' OR old_buffer.field1 = 'HBP00') 

DECLARE
      Operation       NUMBER;
      CustomerCode    CHAR(10 BYTE);
BEGIN

IF DELETING THEN 
  Operation := 3;
  CustomerCode := :old_buffer.field1;
END IF;

IF INSERTING THEN 
  Operation := 1;
  CustomerCode := :new_buffer.field1;
END IF;

IF UPDATING THEN 
  Operation := 2;
  CustomerCode := :new_buffer.field1;
END IF;    

// DO SOMETHING ...

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN ErrorCode := SQLCODE;

END;
```

Answer (score 5):

The NEW values (or NEW_BUFFER as you have renamed them) are only available when INSERTING and UPDATING.  For DELETING you would need to use OLD (OLD_BUFFER).  So your trigger would become:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER test001
  AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON tabletest001
  REFERENCING OLD AS old_buffer NEW AS new_buffer 
  FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new_buffer.field1 = 'HBP00' OR old_buffer.field1 = 'HBP00')
```

You may need to add logic inside the trigger to cater for code that updates field1 from 'HBP000' to something else.

Comment: I've figured it out 10 minutes ago ;-) Thanks. Alberto

Answer (score 1):

Separate it into 2 triggers. One for the deletion and one for the insertion\ update.

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to know how to identify the operation. Alberto

Comment: @LeftyX That's why you should accept devio's answer, not Tony Andrews.