# Oracle trigger to update a field (field+1 and field -1) when inserting and deleting

Tags: oracle, triggers

I need to make a trigger that when inserting or deleting an employee (EMPLOYERS TABLE), the attribute EMPTOTAL from table SHOPS UPDATE.

EMPLOYERS table has a field (and foreign key) called SHOP that references the SHOPS table.

I know it should be something similar to this, but I don't have any example that involves more than 1 table on my exercises.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPD_EMPTOTAL BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE ON EMPLOYERS FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
UPDATE SHOPS SET EMPTOTAL=EMPTOTAL+1;
ELSIF DELETING THEN
UPDATE SHOPS SET EMPTOTAL=EMPTOTAL-1;
END IF;

END;
```

(I've tried other things like UPDATE sentence or declaring a variable for the shop, but I'm not clear about that, so I just parsed here the code that I'm most sure about).

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons for negative votes, and also [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORACLE and TRIGGERS (inserted, updated, deleted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965521/oracle-and-triggers-inserted-updated-deleted)

Comment: So if you know there is a `shop` column that forms the relationship between the two tables.... the update statements should perhaps have a `where` clause for that column, and the corresponding value from the triggering row's [pseudorecord](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-4CF74E99-8859-4AB1-96E7-07898A2ABB9E)?

Answer (score 0):

This may be all that's needed to get your trigger working:

```
create or replace trigger upd_emptotal
   before insert or delete on employers
   for each row
declare
begin
   if inserting
   then
      -- Update only shop total for the shop
      -- in the employer record.
      -- :new.shop is the value being inserted in the table.

      update shops
         set emptotal = emptotal + 1
       where shop = :new.shop;
   elsif deleting
   then
      -- Update only shop total for the shop
      -- in the employer record.
      -- :old.shop is the value in the record being deleted.
      update shops
         set emptotal = emptotal - 1
       where shop = :old.shop;
   end if;

end;
```